# Difference between "in progress" and "in process"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

When reporting on a project that is still being worked on, do you call it *in progress* or do you call it *in process*?

I have heard both, and both make sense in their own way. I want to know what both the descriptivists and prescriptivists have to say.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Describing a project as **in process** sounds pretty odd to me, but apparently the form does occur - although **in progress** is about 5 times more common, as [this NGram](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=is%20in%20process,is%20in%20progress&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) clearly shows.
[image: .]

[This chart](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=is%20in%20process%20of,is%20in%20progress%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) specifically for **in process of** [**changing**, *for example*] strongly suggests the usage is falling out of favour.
[image]

Comment: I obviously can't speak for everyone, but I have always said *in progress* but *in the process of*.  *In progress of* sounds odd to me; I would not have understood it without the comparison given.

Answer (score 10):

What I have to say:

> The writing of my project is currently in progress.

or

> My project is currently in the process of being written.

Comment: I would say *in **the** process* [of being written]

Comment: Before consulting Google books I'd have thought your second sentence was simply sloppy English, with the word "the" conspicuous by its absence. I now know better, but the evidence does suggest it's "dated".

Comment: In computing, a distinction is made between "in process" and "out of process". The process is the algorithm currently loaded and into which the Instruction Pointer is currently pointing and executing instructions in the CPU or central processing unit.  A call to a subroutine can be "in process" if it is already loaded into memory and part of the currently executing algorithm. A call to  a subroutine can be "out of process" if the CPU must perform operating system kernel interrupt operations to fetch the subroutine from secondary storage before executing it.

Comment: These two mutually exclusive process types arose out of the need to conserve memory and enable code reuse. They are still common parlance in operating system jargon. By extension one can refer to any sequential procedure that is "currently in process" and ready to execute as opposed to the opposite state of a procedure that is "out of process" and requiring another high level process to interrupt the current execution and run to  successful completion before the next instruction can be preformed, incurring substantial overheads.

Answer (score 1):

To me being in process implies that a process is proceeding to a conclusion.

Being in progress implies that it is progressing or moving forward to a point or of completion.